# why is a console app affected by having SSMS open

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a console app (c#) which opens a connection to a sql database, executes a stored procedure and then exits.
The stored procedure times itself (using getdate and datediff) and returns the timings to the console app.
The stored procedure always reports taking about 100 milliseconds to execute.

Running the console app repeatedly gives a consistent set of timings
(including 300 ms for the ExecuteReader command)

However what I discovered by accident and can reliably reproduce is the following effect:
If I open SSMS and connect to the database, then run the console app twice, the ExecuteReader in the console app is significantly faster the second time.

Note you don't have to run or even open the stored procedure in SSMS, you simply have to connect to the database

The second run of the console app is being significantly affected and indeed improved by having SSMS open and connected to the same database
For example

```
ExecuteReader when SSMS is not open 300 ms
ExecuteReader when SSMS is not open 300 ms
ExecuteReader when SSMS is not open 300 ms
Open SSMS and connect to database
First ExecuteReader when SSMS is open and connected to same database 300 ms
Second ExecuteReader with SSMS open and connected 10 ms !!!
Third ExecuteReader with SSMS open and connected 10 ms
Fourth ExecuteReader with SSMS open and connected 10 ms
Close SSMS
ExecuteReader back to reporting 300 ms to execute
```

In other words the time reported for ExecuteReader is less than the amount of time the stored procedure takes to run

Note the stored procedure always takes the same amount of time to run.

It seems almost like SSMS has a kind of cache that the console app is allowed to use.

Can anyone shed any light on this?
sys.dm_exec_connections shows no differences between all the various connections

The SSMS is v17.3 connecting to a sql server 2008 R2 SP2 database

Comment: Did you run the test with SSMS open in one run? Or different runs?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. The console app opens a connection, runs the stored procedure and exits. Each run is consistent before SSMS is opened and for the first run after SSMS is opened. Thereafter the behaviour is again consistent but different to before SSMS was opened

Comment: This most likely has something to do with connection pooling. You could repro it by creating another application that merely connects to the same database and then "closes" that connection, meaning the connection is returned to the pool but still open.

Comment: Does the console app immediately return to 300ms if you close SSMS?

Comment: @CodeCaster, SSMS and the console app will run in different app domains so there will be separate connection pools.

Comment: Good question: yes the ExecuteReader immediately returns to reporting 300 ms after SSMS is closed.

Comment: @Dan I thought so as well (couldn't find documentation that quickly), but isn't there some kind of lower-level connection pool that under the appdomain-specific pools?

Comment: With regard to connection pooling: if it was some affect of connection pooling (across different apps?) that might explain an affect on how long it takes to open a connection, but I cannot see how pooling would affect the time taken for ExecuteReader

Comment: @CodeCaster, the only think I can think of that could result in these symptoms is credential caching at the OS level. The pools themselves should be entirely independent, both in separate processes and app domains.

Comment: @Dan alright, thanks.

Comment: @user2849221 could you show some relevant SQL and C# code, especially your ExecuteReader timing?

Comment: @user2849221, please join [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163188/chat-of-question-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-48262494-why-is-a-console-ap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do make sure that you do not have `AUTO_CLOSE` set for your database. According to the discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163188/chat-of-question-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-48262494-why-is-a-console-ap), it does seem that this is set to ON.

[Quoted from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/policy-based-management/set-the-auto-close-database-option-to-off)

> [When] AUTO_CLOSE is set ON [it] can cause performance degradation on
>   frequently accessed databases because of the increased overhead of
>   opening and closing the database after each connection. AUTO_CLOSE
>   also flushes the procedure cache after each connection.
>
> Best Practices Recommendations
>
> If a database is accessed frequently, set the AUTO_CLOSE option to OFF
>   for the database.

You can turn of `AUTO_CLOSE` by running the following query (as suggested by [Dan Guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman)):

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF;
```

Comment: just to confirm: with autoclose set to false the first run of the console app reported 300ms for ExecuteQuery but 10 ms thereafter whether or not SSMS was open

Comment: @user2849221, that may be due to standard data caching. SQL Server will need to read data from storage initially. Subsequent data access will be from memory unless the buffers are reused by more recent requests.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that this behavior comes from the [Connection Pool Feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling).
Could you try a [SqlConnection.ClearAllPools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools?view=netframework-4.7.1) after each call in the console app.

Comment: I have put ClearAllPools before, after, and before and after the ExecuteQuery without any discernible affect.